# How to check richtextbox is empty in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Whenever we have display record on vf page , when we have decided record cannot display when richtextbox is empty. I am using apex class.

Answer (score 2):

Use isBlank(String) method of the [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) Class to check if richtextbox is empty.

Example:

```
 String.isBlank(record.Rich_Text_Field__c);
```